# htaccess to different sub folder through URL

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess

I have 3 web apps, all written in ReactJS, folder structure as below:

/main.mysite.com

/sub1.mysite.com

/sub2.mysite.com

Would like to access sub1.mysite.com and sub2.mysite.com through 
main.mysite.com.

Example:

main.mysite.com/sub1/* would access to sub1.mysite.com web app.

I have created a htaccess inside /main.mysite.com but it doesn't seem to be able to route to the other sub1/sub2 domain.

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sub1.mysite.com/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(.*)$ /sub1/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sub2.mysite.com/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(.*)$ /sub2/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What is `DocumentRoot` for `main.mysite.com` ?

Comment: @anubhava all 3 sites are on same level of hierarchy

Comment: Yes that I realize. Can you share VirtualHost configuration of any of 3 sites.